# How do I specify in which direction to round the average of two floats that differ by the LSB of their significand?

Tags: c, floating-point, mathematical-optimization

I'm working on a Nelder-Mead optimization routine in C that involves taking the average of two `float`s. In rare (but perfectly reproducible) circumstances, the two `float`s, say `x` and `y`, differ only by the least significant bit of their significand. When the average is taken, rounding errors imply that the result will be either `x` or `y`.

I'd like to specify that rounding should always be towards the second `float`. That is, I cannot simply specify that rounding should be towards zero, or infinity, because I do not know in advance whether `x` will be larger than `y`.

(How) can I do that?

Comment: Can't you just compare those two floats, and set rounding to either zero, minus infinity, or plus infinity depending on the result of the comparison?

Comment: But you can determine at the time you're rounding whether `x > y`, right?

Comment: You could, but there's a much simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a hardware rounding mode for that. You have to write your own function, then,

```
double average(double x, double y) {
    double a = 0.5*(x+y);
    return (a == x) ? y : a;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was about to suggest.  Regardless of the rounding mode, `a` can only equal `x` if (a) the described condition holds, or (b) `x == y`.  In both cases this produces the desired result, and does so very efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You could recognize the special case and pick the value you would like to return.

The values that are of interest are:

- When the values have the same sign and exponent and only differs by one in the mantissa.
- When the values have the same sign, the exponents differs by one, and the one with the larger exponent has a mantissa of 0 and the other a mantissa filled with ones.

In fact, if you are using IEEE-754 numbers (which you probably are) you can perform both tests at once (after checking for things like Zero, Inf, and Nan):

```
if (   repr1 + 1 == repr2
    || repr2 + 1 == repr1)
  ....
```

The reason for this is that the exponent is placed right next to the mantissa, and if the mantissa is all ones, the add will continue up into the exponent field.

However, talking about this, I would suggest another strategy. Instead of simply returning the second number, you could check the second lest significant bit and decide if you would like to round up or down. That way the rounding errors would be evenly distributed.